# htaccess combine/reduce rewrite conditions into one (or at least fewer)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a course booking component that is unfortunately providing three different URLs to the same page, depending on whether you go in via a menu link, breadcrumb or link within the component.

As such, I've been adding a new rewrite condition to an htaccess file, per course, as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/smsts/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/smsts/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/smsts/book-now/1$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /citb/smsts/book-now/1-smsts [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/smsts-refresher/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/smsts-refresher/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/smsts-refresher/book-now/2$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /citb/smsts-refresher/book-now/2-smsts-refresher [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/sssts/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/sssts/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/sssts/book-now/3$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /citb/sssts/book-now/3-sssts [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/sssts-refresher/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/sssts-refresher/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/sssts-refresher/book-now/4$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /citb/sssts-refresher/book-now/4-sssts-refresher [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/health-and-safety-awareness/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/health-and-safety-awareness/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/health-and-safety-awareness/book-now/7$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /citb/health-and-safety-awareness/book-now/7-health-and-safety-awareness [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iosh/managing-safely/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iosh/managing-safely/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iosh/managing-safely/book-now/8$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /iosh/managing-safely/book-now/8-iosh-managing-safely [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iosh/working-safely/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iosh/working-safely/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iosh/working-safely/book-now/9$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /iosh/working-safely/book-now/9-iosh-working-safely [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-aid/3-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-aid/3-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-aid/3-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now/5$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /first-aid/3-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now/5-3-day-first-aid-at-work [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-aid/1-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-aid/1-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-aid/1-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now/6$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /first-aid/1-day-first-aid-at-work/book-now/6-1-day-first-aid-at-work [R=301,NC,L]
```

This is obviously not a desirable approach to keep repeating every time there's a new course to be added (and yes I know the best solution would actually be to hack the component around so that it's not doing this) so I was wondering if there was a way of making this more generic, either with the one rewrite condition or maybe one per category or however it could be best generalised?

Each desired/destination URL will follow the following format:

```
/[category]/[course]/book-now/[id]-[alias]
```

Where, from the first example above:

```
category = citb
course = smsts
id = 1
alias = smsts
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i don't think *(or i don't know how)* you could reduce all your redirections (you can't actually guess the missing number in your 2 first conditions).
But you could actually handle all your 3rd conditions with  :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/book-now/([0-9]+)$ /$1/$2/book-now/$3-$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

And combine your 2 first conditions by using `(/?)` at the end.

That would make :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/book-now/([0-9]+)$ /$1/$2/book-now/$3-$2 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/citb/smsts/book-now(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /citb/smsts/book-now/1-smsts [R=301,NC,L]
...
```

**PS** : You wrote :

Each desired/destination URL will follow the following format:

```
/[category]/[course]/book-now/[id]-[alias]
```

Where, from the first example above:

```
category = citb
course = smsts
id = 1
alias = smsts
```

But actually, for your `/iosh/working-safely/book-now/9` url, your format is :

```
alias = [category]-[course]
```

Since it becomes

```
/iosh/working-safely/book-now/9-iosh-working-safely
```

Not sure if it's a mistake in your htaccess, seems important to notice.

Hope it helps !